# Generating PDF from twig view using KnpSnappyBundle

Tags: symfony, pdf, twig

I try to generate a pdf from a twig view using KnpSnappyBundle, it starts loading until "Maximum execution time of 360 seconds exceeded", the problem is that I can find the pdf file in the temp folder generated, but it needs to get downloaded in the browser for the user.

```
           try {
             $html = $this->renderView('ordreexecute.html.twig',['demande' => $demande,'username'=>$username]);

            $filename = 'myFirstSnappyPDF';

             return new Response(
                $this->knpSnappy->getOutputFromHtml($html),
                200,
                array(
                    'Content-Type' => 'application/pdf',
                    'Content-Disposition' => 'attachement; filename="' . $filename . '.pdf"'
                )
            );
            }
            catch(\Exception $e){
                error_log($e->getMessage());
            }
```

Comment: up the execution time and let it play its course to see if it throws something else at some point?

Comment: I actually did that and nothing happened

Comment: As in - it kept executing and never finished or it stopped loading and you got a blank page?

Comment: it keeps executing until time is out and if I set time so high it's a never-ending loading .

Comment: Try to add breakpoints to see how far it gets before it gets stuck - the document is being created after all. Maybe also worth checking the application / server logs to see what it's actually trying to do.

Comment: Maybe your PDF is too heavy, to check just try to create a simple PDF with simple HTML and tell us if it works

Comment: yes if I do that it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, after all, it turns out even when I used absolute_url to load all CSS and JS it wasn't working properly, I checked this issue https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpSnappyBundle/issues/82 and it worked !!